# don't send the form message if input is empty

Tags: php, forms, validation, contact-form

i do have a little problem with my contact.php :(

I needed for my page a contact form (very simple, just name, email and message).
It works perfectly but it sends the message even if the inputs are empty. My inputs do have "required" but it doesn't seem to work. My php skills are not that great. But you understand for sure where the problem is.

If there are empty fields, the form should not send the message and show an alert.

My current code:

**HTML**

```
    <form method="post" id="myform" action="contact.php">
        <div class="field half first">
            <label for="name">Ihr Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="field half">
            <label for="email">Ihre E-Mail</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="message">Ihre Nachricht</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li>
                <a href="" class="button submit">Senden</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php 
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'mail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Nachricht von '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'Von: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Nachricht: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'Von: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Antworte an: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Ich bedanke mich für Ihre Nachricht. Bald werde ich Sie kontaktieren./ Thank you for your message.');
    window.location = 'http://';
    </script>
    <?php
     }
else { ?>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Senden fehlgeschlagen./ Could not send the message');
    window.location = 'http://';
     </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Any ideas, how to fix that small problem? :(

Comment: Simple: `if(!)` => http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Also, change the html anchor to button

Answer (score 4):

I think if your goal is to prevent someone send a blank message/contact, just use "required" in the end of your input tag like this :

```html
<input type="text" name="something" required/>
```

or in your case, it should be like this :

```html
<form method="post" id="myform" action="contact.php">
        <div class="field half first">
            <label for="name">Ihr Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field half">
            <label for="email">Ihre E-Mail</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="message">Ihre Nachricht</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li>
                <a href="" class="button submit">Senden</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

The "required" is a simple html5 tag attribute that helps you prevent someone send a blank form. I hope it works on you, make sure you are working with html5.

Comment: tried, it shows the "thank you for your alert" message, then i have to click okay and it sends the text anyway, with a blank input mail

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in PHP called `empty()`. You can combine this with the `$_POST` function like this example:

```
<?php
// The form is submitted.
if(isset($_POST["submit_button"])) {
    // Now check if the posted input element is empty, if empty stop by echo a error message
    // Otherwhise continue executing script
    if(empty($_POST["form_name"])) {
        echo "You forgot to fill in this form-element.";

    }else{
        // Continue
    }
}
?>
```

Read more about this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

Check if the form is submitted using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function:

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

Then, check if the fields are filled using [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function:

> empty — Determine whether a variable is empty

```
// this will return true if the Submit Button is clicked
if(isset($_POST["submit_button"])) {

    if(empty($_POST['name']) {
        echo "Name is not filled";
    } else if (empty($_POST['email']) {
        echo "Email is not filled";
    } else if (empty($_POST['message']) {
        echo "Message is not filled";
    } else {
        // Your original code
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, my original code is in else but then it opens my contact.php (if(isset($_POST["submit_button"]))...) and the message sends anyway.